# SharePoint Tools - Visual studio 2012 - Wierd Deployment Error

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(375,5): error : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file

... Then references a project file name to another SharePoint solution that is no longer in the solution and has ben refactored (renamed) anyway. Has no dependency from the one I am trying to deploy (as far as I know) - Anyone any ideas how to troubleshoot and fix. I have had a poke around in the project file but cant see anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is:

- a number of previously created feature dependencies that were created to a SharePoint project in the same solution. The name of that dependent project was subsequently changed - the feature dependencies must presumably retain a link to the old project name which no longer exists.

Comment: When changing reference names of assemblies in the GAC you need to restart visual studio to reload the App Domain, same with Powershell.